# How to clear a textbox if i drag the text out

Tags: vb.net

I have code to drag files into a textbox, but I would also like to have code to drag the file out of the textbox, thus clearing it.

Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Showing some current code would help

Comment: Are you dragging within your own application?  It doesn't make sense to clear the TextBox until an actual drop has been made, since the user might cancel the drag.  If within your own app then you can set the TextBox itself as the data of the drag enabling you to both grab the data and clear the TextBox when the drop is made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`DoDragDrop`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dodragdrop.aspx) method to do a drag & drop operation. It returns a [`DragDropEffects`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dragdropeffects.aspx) value that specifies if the data actually has been dropped somewhere in which case you can clear the text box.

Since a drag & drop operation shouldn't start before the mouse has been moved a bit while pressing the mouse button you need to check for that in the `MouseDown` and `MouseMove` events. [`SystemInformation.DragSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.dragsize.aspx) tells you how far the mouse should be moved before a drag & drop operation starts.

In the `MouseDown` event check if you actually want to start a drag (i.e left button is pressed and text box actually contains text). Then create a rectangle using the mouse location and the size given by `SystemInformation.DragSize`. In the `MouseMove` event check if the mouse is dragged outside the rectangle and call `DoDragDrop`:

```
Private _dragStart As Boolean
Private _dragBox As Rectangle

Private Sub srcTextBox_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles srcTextBox.MouseDown
    ' a drag starts if the left mouse button is pressed and the text box actually contains any text
    _dragStart = e.Button = MouseButtons.Left And Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(srcTextBox.Text)

    If _dragStart Then
        Dim dragSize As Size = SystemInformation.DragSize
        _dragBox = New Rectangle(New Point(e.X - (dragSize.Width \ 2),
                                           e.Y - (dragSize.Height \ 2)), dragSize)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub srcTextBox_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles srcTextBox.MouseUp
    _dragStart = False
End Sub

Private Sub srcTextBox_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles srcTextBox.MouseMove
    If Not _dragStart Or
       (e.Button And MouseButtons.Left) <> MouseButtons.Left Or
       _dragBox.Contains(e.X, e.Y) Then Return

    Dim data As New DataObject()
    data.SetData(srcTextBox.Text)
    ' you can optionally add more formats required by valid drag destinations:
    ' data.SetData(DataFormats.UnicodeText, Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(srcTextBox.Text))
    ' data.SetData("UTF-8", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(srcTextBox.Text))
    ' data.SetData("UTF-32", Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(srcTextBox.Text))

    Dim dropEffect As DragDropEffects = srcTextBox.DoDragDrop(data, DragDropEffects.Move)
    If (dropEffect = DragDropEffects.Move) Then
        srcTextBox.Text = ""
    End If

    _dragStart = False
    _dragBox = Rectangle.Empty
End Sub

Private Sub destTextBox_DragOver(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DragEventArgs) Handles destTextBox.DragOver
    If e.Data.GetDataPresent(GetType(String)) Then
        e.Effect = e.AllowedEffect And DragDropEffects.Move
    Else
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub destTextBox_DragDrop(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DragEventArgs) Handles destTextBox.DragDrop
    If e.Data.GetDataPresent(GetType(String)) Then
        destTextBox.Text = e.Data.GetData(GetType(String)).ToString()
    End If
End Sub
```

Dragging the mouse in a TextBox usually starts text selection. The above code changes this behavior. Users can't use the mouse any more to select text. This is obviously not a good idea since users wouldn't expect that. To allow both text selection with the mouse and dragging you need to control the selection mechanism. This means you need to create your own text box class.

I would suggest a different approach: Use a label that shows the value as the dragging source and/or destination. To allow editing you can create a hidden text box. If the user double clicks on the label you hide the label and show the text box. After the user finishes editing (by hitting enter or cancel) or if the text box looses focus you hide the text box and show the label again.

Comment: I didn't want to drag the source textbox to a destination textbox, so I changed the "Handles destTextBox.DragDrop" to "Handles Me.DragDrop" and it worked the way I wanted!! Thanks pescolino!!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the DragLeave Event on the TextBox
Easiest way will probably be to store it as a variable or in clip board if leaving app.

```
    Private Sub TheTextBox_DragLeave(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TheTextBox.DragLeave
Clipboard.SetText(TheTextBox.Text)
TheTextBox.Clear() 'Optional

End Sub
```

Then you'll need to code what happens when you mouse up of course, or drag into or whatever.  You could clear the textbox in one of these steps.  Depends on your implementation.

Comment: Did you mean to put the `'Optional` comment on the clipboard-related line?

Comment: If you want to clear the text box use TheTextBox.Clear() otherwise doen't put that line in your code

Comment: The clearing of the textbox was the question, not the potential to store the data: that's why I was questioning what you commented as the optional part in your answer.